# Как найти нужную секцию в файле ELF?

Tags: gcc, elf, linux

Например, есть код:

```
void func() __attribute__ ((section (".func")));

void func() {
}
```

который перейдет в секцию .func. Как найти эту секцию в итоговом файле ELF?

Answer (score 2):

1. Для просмотра файла достаточно использовать readelf и objdump.
2. Для изменения файла нужно писать код, который анализирует файл согласно спецификации. Можно посмотреть на исходники GNU libextractor: там есть анализ ELF.